# Preg_Match a textbox submit

Tags: php

I want to submit a simple textbox to return a value after preg_match?
For example,

I would enter in the textbox:
You found luke in his house, kitchen

i want to extract "house, kitchen" otherwise preg_match it? Not sure how would do this

Comment: do you want the regular expression for that ?

Comment: Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post codes and efforts!

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to start it.

Comment: Before you use preg_match exactly what do you want it to do for you? Those two(house and kitchen), are they keywords, you are looking for? or they are just any words that has a colon after the first word. Please, Lets us know

Comment: they will be any words which has a colon after the first word, However always only be 2 words such as house, kitchen or hotel, room?

I need to echo the two words and nothing else? would preg_match be wrong way doing it

Comment: are the combinations known in advance? Or can people write any two word combination like car, backseat / church, chapel / store, floor / xxx, yyy ...

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want to accomplish:

```
preg_match('/\b(kitchen\w+)\b/', $string, $matches); // matches kitchen
preg_match('/\b(house\w+)\b/', $string, $matches); // matches kitchen
```

You might be able to add wildcards for other match.

For more check out this references:

[PHP preg_match reference.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "You found luke in his house, kitchen";
```

In case the word combination is always at the end of the string you could go with `explode()`:

```
$words = explode(" ", $str);
$nWords = count($words);
$combo = (strpos($words[$nWords-1], ",") !== false)?$words[$nWords-1]." ".$words[$nWords]:'incorrect form'; // only when , is in second last 'word'
```

When you know all combo's in advance you could opt for:

```
$knownCombos = array('house, kitchen', 'house, bathroom', 'house, basement');
foreach($knownCombos as $i => $search) {
    if(strpos($str, $search) !== false) {
        $combo = $search;
        break;
    }
}
```